Horizontally Align Lists in Proofs
Is there any way to make the 1. and bullet point align with the rest in the proof environment?
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{itemize}
                \item For any $f$ there would always exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=f$. Hence it is reflexive.
                \item If $fRg$ then there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g$. Then we see that $g=f$. Hence $gRf$ and $R$ is symmetric.
                \item If $fRg$ there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= g(x)$ and similarly for $gRh$. Assume $f(x)=1, g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=2$, $fRg \wedge gRh \notimplies fRh (1\neq2)$. Hence $R$ is not transitive.
              \end{itemize}
        \item \begin{itemize}
                \item Assume $x=1\in \mathbb{Z}$. However $1\cdot 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Hence $R$ is not reflexive.
                \item Assume $xy \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Then $yx \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ since multiplication is commutative. Hence $R$ is symmetric.
                \item Consider $x=2,y=4$ and $z=1$. Then $xy=9\equiv0 \pmod{4}$ and $yz=4\equiv 0\pmod{4}$. However notice that $xz=2\not\equiv0 \pmod{4}$. Hence $R$ is not transitive.
              \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}



Add some text before the first enumerate.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@egreg so there is not other way to format?

Mathematics isn’t just jotting down symbols.

As mentioned @egreg in his comment, you need to add some text after \begin{proof}. For example invisible xharacter ~:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\newcommand{\notimplies}{%
  \mathrel{{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\not\phantom{=}$\hidewidth\cr$\implies$}}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}~
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \begin{itemize}
                \item For any $f$ there would always exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=f$. Hence it is reflexive.
                \item If $fRg$ then there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g$. Then we see that $g=f$. Hence $gRf$ and $R$ is symmetric.
                \item If $fRg$ there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= g(x)$ and similarly for $gRh$. Assume $f(x)=1$, $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=2$, $fRg \wedge gRh \notimplies fRh (1\neq2)$. Hence $R$ is not transitive.
              \end{itemize}
        \item \begin{itemize}
                \item Assume $x=1\in \mathbb{Z}$. However $1\cdot 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Hence $R$ is not reflexive.
                \item Assume $xy \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Then $yx \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ since multiplication is commutative. Hence $R$ is symmetric.
                \item Consider $x=2,y=4$ and $z=1$. Then $xy=9\equiv0 \pmod{4}$ and $yz=4\equiv 0\pmod{4}$. However notice that $xz=2\not\equiv0 \pmod{4}$. Hence $R$ is not transitive.
              \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}


